# Hugo FontAwesome import

Tags: font-awesome, hugo, postcss

Does anyone know the correct way to setup Hugo, using PostCSS to move fonts into public when building - but also be served locally in memory when running in local dev server?

I have tried `postcss-url` but that seems to only want to copy the files to a location, then the pathing doesn't work.  Manually setting up a copy to public will get out of hand and then would't work for local dev.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand, what are you missing with the [`static files` feature](https://gohugo.io/content-management/static-files/)?